# Setup of nginx with node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have setup nginx as a front end to an node.js app.

My nginx conf is:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /tmp/logs/error.log;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  access_log  /tmp/logs/access.log;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

  # BELOW IS THE PART TO PROXY MY NODE.JS APP

  upstream node_entry {
    server unix:/tmp/express.sock
    fail_timeout=0;
  }
  server {
    listen 8888;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name localhost;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://node_entry;
    }
  }
}
```

My node.js app is:

```
express = require('express');
app = express.createServer();
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  res.send('TEST');
});
app.listen('/tmp/express.sock');
```

When I issue a:

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8888/test'

I get an error instead of proxying to my node.js app.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something similar, but it's all on one host, and I'm using a predefined port number that nginx and node both know (though I'd rather use your way if you can get it working).

Does it work if you have node listen on a specific port, and proxy_pass to `http://127.0.0.1:{that_port}`? (assuming both are on the same server...)

Comment: You might check into the socket permissions as well, per this article:
http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/nodejs-set-unix-socket-permissions


`var http = require("http");
var oldUmask = process.umask(0000);
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
  // ...
});

server.listen("/some/socket/path", function() {
  process.umask(oldUmask);
});`

Comment: I'll check this but as I use /tmp I though I should not have any problem with rights.

Comment: Thanks, after I executed: `chmod o+w /tmp/xxx.sock`, it works!